# How to check for const correctness in C++ with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm actively learning C++ and am using the following cmake opinions to Sanitize my code and was wondering if there was any way to programatically check for `const correctness`. If my code was not const correct would the complier throw an error?

Is there any way to check? I swiftly read the rules and got confused since I'm new with C++.

```cpp
##############################################################################
# Options

# We use a cached string variable instead of the standard (boolean) OPTION
# command so that we can default to auto-detecting optional depencies, while
# still providing a mechanism to force/disable these optional dependencies, as
# prescribed in http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/automagic.xml

option (ENABLE_ASAN "Enable Address Sanitizer" ON)

option (ENABLE_UBSAN "Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer" ON)

# Reference code from https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
# Enable Address Sanitizer

if (ENABLE_UBSAN)
    set (_FLAGS "-fsanitize=undefined")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${_FLAGS}")
endif ()

if (ENABLE_ASAN)
    set (_FLAGS "-fsanitize=address")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${_FLAGS}")
endif ()
```

Comment: const-correctness is not enforceable. I don't know of a tool that finds non-const objects that could be declared const. I doubt one exists, since not being const-correct does not introduce potential errors or anything.

Comment: Also, just because something **could** be made const doesn't mean it should be. Non-const doesn't mean it **will** change the state of the object, it means it's **allowed** to do so.

Comment: Since changing a `non-const` variable to a `const` can induce (sometimes, but not necessarily always desirable) overload resolution changes. I don;t think it's even possible to write such a tool that would catch any but the most trivial of cases.